# Implementing threadpool in JAX-RS api

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, jax-rs, threadpoolexecutor

In a JAX-RS api, I want to implement a thread pool to allot new incoming requests to a new thread from the pool.
My api currently looks like this:

```
@Service
@Path("/")
public class SampleService {
    @POST
    @Path("/pass")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response sampleApi(Incoming bean){
        //do some processing on bean
        File file = getUserData(bean);
        //do some processing on file
        return Response.status(200).entity("OK").build();
    }

    private File getUserData(Incoming bean){
        //fetch data from external service through SOAP
        //put in one file and return the file
    }
}
```

My threadpool implementation looks like this

```
@Component
public class OnlineThreadPool {

    private static ThreadPoolExecutor pool;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize(){
        pool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(3, 20, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(3));
    }

    public ThreadPoolExecutor getThreadPoolExecutor(){
        return pool;
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void cleanUp(){
        pool.shutdown();
    }
}
```

I want to set up a asynchronous api so that on POST request for this api, new thread is obtained from threadpool and req is put in the new thread and response is returned without waiting for the thread to complete the processing of the request.

Any resources on how to implement this would be of great help.

**EDIT:**
Thanks to thilo`s answer, New thread is being created for each request but it terminates before the whole processing. But as soon as the parent thread calling this new thread terminates, child thread is also terminating. How to detach these parent child threads?

**EDIT:**
There was a null pointer exception in my process flow due to which thread execution was not completed. Since I have not given exception handler till now it was not showing any errors, just stopping without any exception message.

Comment: So the HTTP client does not need to get a result in the response? Just send the HTTP response right away, and continue processing in the background?

Comment: If so, inject your OnlineThreadPool into your SampleService and in the sampleAPI method submit a Runnable to the getThreadPoolExecutor. And don't make the pool static.

Comment: yeah client does not need to wait for processing to finish and it can respond right away.
To submit runnable , do i need to implement runnable in my class? Y should I not make pool static?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@POST
@Path("/pass")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response sampleApi(final Incoming bean){
    onlineThreadPool.getThreadPoolExecutor().submit(new Runnable(){
       @Override public void run(){
          //do some processing on bean
          File file = getUserData(bean);
         //do some processing on file
       }});
    return Response.status(200).entity("OK").build();
}
```

Comment: If you are on Java8, you can remove a lot of this boilerplate.

Comment: Ohk. so on request, new thread is initiated and processing is done in that but as soon as return is executed, new thread stops processing.. do i need to add somewhere about detaching from parent thread?

Comment: There is no "new thread" (unless the pool is busy) it just uses one from the pool. And processing should not stop when the method returns.

Answer (score 2):

This is how it should look like. Notice that I am using constructor injection to inject your `OnlineThreadPool` dependency and Java 8 lambda for creating the `Runnable`.

```
@Service
@Path("/")
public class SampleService {

     private OnlineThreadPool pool;

     public SampleService(OnlineThreadPool pool) {
         this.pool = pool;
     } //constructor injection 

     @POST
     @Path("/pass")
     @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
     public Response sampleApi(Incoming bean){
         pool.getThreadPoolExecutor().submit(() -> {
              File file = getUserData(bean);
              //some other processing
         });
         return Response.status(200).entity("OK").build();
     }
}
```